# What is the current limit for LLMs regarding the size of the context that can be fed to them?

Tags: large-language-models, gpt

Is there a limitation in current large language models (LLMs) in terms of practical processing time or memory resources when it comes to digesting the context provided by users? What I mean regarding context is the data fed to LLMs post-training, like feeding a selection of books about a certain topic.

Answer (score 3):

Most state of the art LLMs nowadays are based on an architecture called *Transformer*, which uses a technique called *attention*, which scales quadratically with the input size. Thus, for an input of 1 million tokens, you'll have to create a matrix of size $(10^6)^2 = 10^{12}$ numbers, which are usually `float32`, which are composed of 4 bytes each. In other words, a matrix that is 4 Terabytes in size.

Alternatives have been proposed. For example linear transformers, sparse attention, RMTs, and quantization, but they are not as effective as the full transformer model.